# Why should I install my programs into my SSD? Shouldn't disk accesses be infrequent after loading to memory?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, virtual-memory, computer-architecture

I'm wondering why people always say to put the Operating System and the program installations on the SSD (as opposed to a larger magnetic disk HDD).

As I understand, in the memory hierarchy, programs should be loaded from disk to memory and be accessed from the process through levels of caches.

It seems to me, then, unless the process must fetch new data/instruction from disk to memory constantly, it shouldn't matter much if a program is installed on a SSD or a HDD -- perhaps it'd only affect the initial load time.

Surely a large program is going to need a large virtual memory, and probably some good swap on disk, but I think that's a separate issue, in any case handled by the OS.

Comment: Users want to start their computer and run programs as fast as possible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application starts it does not load everything into memory and then start to run. Instead, application code is only loaded as needed and then retained in memory. This might mean loading a few clusters of the application exe, a few more from a dll, back to the exe and then clusters from a different dll. This process could continue until the application window appears and beyond. Initiating a complex operation from a menu or toolbar could require considerable disk access. This can save a great deal of memory for large applications, which is of course where it matters most. Operating systems like Windows, Linux, and the Mac follow the same general principles.

The downside to this loading process is that it means a great deal of head movement with a conventional drive. This will be the case even if the drive had zero fragmentation. The drive is going to spend more time seeking the heads to the required locations than actually reading the data. The OS tries to do this as efficiently as possible and features like prefetch help but the basic problem remains.

A good solution to this is using an SSD. As they have no moving parts seek time is virtually zero and performance is much improved. It so much application performance that improves but application response time. To the user that is often the most important.

From personal experience I can say that an SSD is well worthwhile. Even on an old computer that has only SATA2 and cannot support the full transfer rate capabilities  of the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a program or an OS is a pretty complex process. Some applications require dozens of libraries and other files that are usually scattered over the whole disk. Even more starting an OS requires hundred of files to be read. If everything is located on a SSD those load operations are executed significantly faster.

Hence the more often you start programs the more you will "feel" the difference between an HDD and an SSD. Even if you just start your os and afterwards start your web browser and SSD will significantly increase the speed of both operations.

But as now 1TB SSD are affordable splitting up data is no longer that much important. If you have a HDD you can use it for very large files,the rest can be placed on the SSD.

Comment: You can opt for an all-in-RAM system, where most, if not all, pieces of code required by the OS to function properly would be loaded in your RAM, and reside there between reboots, with the occasional refresh when necessary. This would reduce the I/O on your SSD. It's hard to implement via command line, because it requires to interact with Registry at a deep level, but some third-parties like Tweak-SSD can automate it for you. Raising the threshold for svchost splitting can also help in keeping your overheads light, thus reducing the I/O too.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering why people always say to put the Operating System and
>   the program installations on the SSD (as opposed to a larger magnetic
>   disk HDD).
>
> As I understand, in the memory hierarchy, programs should be loaded
>   from disk to memory and be accessed from the process through levels of
>   caches.
>
> It seems to me, then, unless the process must fetch new
>   data/instruction from disk to memory constantly, it shouldn't matter
>   much if a program is installed on a SSD or a HDD -- perhaps it'd only
>   affect the initial load time.
>
> Surely a large program is going to need a large virtual memory, and
>   probably some good swap on disk, but I think that's a separate issue,
>   in any case handled by the OS.

Let's say a computer is switched on.  So RAM/main memory, is clear.

It now has to load data from Storage (SSD or magnetic spinning disk drive), to RAM. SSD will be much faster.

You write

> Surely a large program is going to need a large virtual memory, and
>   probably some good swap on disk, but I think that's a separate issue,
>   in any case handled by the OS.

It's not just large programs.

If a user has Chrome open with lots of tabs, that could use almost all his RAM up!

My laptop has 16GB RAM, and about 14GB of it is being used by Chrome, with all of chrome's ton of chrome.exe processes summed up

Now suppose I start up another program.

Even if that program (Adobe Premiere Pro, for editing videos), uses a fraction of what Chrome does!! The OS will still have to swap data between RAM and Storage.

And SSD will be much faster, because of all the swapping taking place.

Years ago in the days of DOS, there was a concept of a RAM drive. Whereby a tiny part of the RAM was treated as a Hard Drive!   So you'd refer to e.g. L:\ and write files to it or directories and it'd be fast. And then when you restarted your computer it'd be wiped.

If an OS really did dump everything you need from Storage into RAM, then once it has doone that dump, then it wouldn't make a difference, whether you used SSD or Hard Disk.. but it doesn't. Suppose you open a program, then close it. Should the OS keep that program in RAM. Will it. It's a bit subjective and you can't really control it.

And what if the computer is slow to start up because it's dumping quite an amount, from a slow HDD to RAM. And the user starts opening more programs. An SSD's speed would make a huge difference.